# What will happen when AsyncTasks are full?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask

In Android 7.0:

```
private static final int CORE_POOL_SIZE = Math.max(2, Math.min(CPU_COUNT - 1, 4));
private static final int MAXIMUM_POOL_SIZE = CPU_COUNT * 2 + 1;
private static final int KEEP_ALIVE_SECONDS = 30;
private static final BlockingQueue<Runnable> sPoolWorkQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>(128);
```

**CORE_POOL_SIZE** is the number of initial threads.
**MAXIMUM_POOL_SIZE** means the number of maximum threads *when the queue is full*.
**sPoolWorkQueue** stores tasks waiting for their turn to run.

This seams I can call `executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR)` for 137 tasks max at the same time if my phone has 4 processors.

So what will happen if I call one more **executeOnExecutor()** when already reached **MAXIMUM_POOL_SIZE**, all the threads are running, and **sPoolWorkQueue** is full.

Although such a scenario is rare, I'm really curious because I read someone's old post a few days ago saying AsyncTask's limit caused a crash on his project. He said he had to limit the number of tasks to 128..

Comment: Also [`ThreadPoolExecutor`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) documentation in the section "Rejected tasks". Ps: you reach `MAXIMUM_POOL_SIZE` already when the queue is still empty since it scales up as soon as there is a task and no idle thread. Once all threads are busy, you'll see backlog in the queue. Downscaling the pool will stop at CORE threads though.

Comment: @zapl I didn't know that, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So what will happen if I call one more executeOnExecutor() when already reached MAXIMUM_POOL_SIZE, all the threads are running, and sPoolWorkQueue is full.

You get a `RejectedExecutionException`.

Comment: Thank you! Can I ask you one more question? The same is true for AsyncTask.SERIAL_EXECUTOR too? I mean, calling another execute() when the sPoolWorkQueue is already full?

Comment: @Jenix: I don't think so. The way `SerialExecutor` is written, it seems to have an unbounded `ArrayDeque` of pending tasks and only hands one at a time off to to the standard `ThreadPoolExecutor`. Hence, AFAICT, there is no upper limit, until you run out of heap space.

Comment: Ah, I see. But what about sPoolWorkQueue itself? 'new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>(128)' means it will limit to 128, right?

Comment: @Jenix: Except that `SerialExecutor` serves as a gate, so `SerialExecutor` will contribute at most one task at a time to that queue.